# Android Studio "libc.so.6" not found

Tags: android-studio

I am developing an android app and I am using a third-party library for print job.

The app is running fine but when I tried to access the printer a java exception occurs: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found.`

I tried to download this file from `gclib` and put it in the lib folder, but it did not work.

I am new in android development, and using android studio 2.3.3.

Thanks for the help.